# why does setfield overwrite previous structure?

Tags: matlab, structure

I am rather new to MATLAB and I have an issue building a structure that I can iterate through with another m-file. I have `i` subjects who performed `t` trials with `w` segments in each trial. I now want to store specific timepoints from each segment. Here called `startTime` and `stopTime`. I tried the following (for one subject, one trial):

```
i=1; %Testperson #


% Trial 1
t=1; %Trial #

w=1; %Segment 1

selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'startTime',0.001*5000)
selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'stopTime',24.5*5000)

w=2; %Segment 2

selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'startTime',0.001*5000);
selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'stopTime',24.5*5000);

w=3; %Segment 3

selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'startTime',0.001*5000);
selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'stopTime',24.5*5000);

w=4; %Segment 4

selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'startTime',0.001*5000);
selectedData = setfield('selectedData',['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'stopTime',24.5*5000);
```

It seems that `setfield` overwrites the previous values I want to store? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above code is really what you're executing, I'm somewhat surprised it actually works.

The first argument to `setfield` should be the structure you want to change, not its name as a string.
So try:

```
selectedData = setfield(selectedData,['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'startTime',0.001*5000);
selectedData = setfield(selectedData,['Subj' num2str(i)],['Trial' num2str(t)],{w},'stopTime',24.5*5000);
```

**But:**
This looks like a not really well designed structure. You shouldn't use "enumerating" fieldnames as indices, when you can use proper indices as well.

In your case you should rather use structure-array, e.g. like this:

```
subjects(i).trials(t).startTime(w) = xx;
subjects(i).trials(t).stopTime(w) = yy;
```

This makes things a) much easier to code and b) allows much easier access to the data later on.

Comment: Funny how such a simple edit can seem impossible to solve. Perfect! It worked like a charm!

Comment: As an aside `setfield` & `getfield` are kind of discouraged. You should rather use dynamic fieldnames. See e.g.: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/